# Sequence identification for these numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sorry for my English.
Can someone help me find the generating formula for these numbers?

$$[255,2915,16383,62499,186623,470595,1048575,2125763,3999999,7086243,11943935,19307235,...]$$

All I know is that they're of the form $n(n-2)$, but I'd like to know the formula that generates all of them and only them.

Thanks!

Comment: The sequence does not appear on the OEIS (Online Encylcopedia of Integer Sequences), but it does suggest your sequence to be $4x^{6} + 24x^{5} + 60x^{4} + 80x^{3} + 60x^{2} + 24x + 3$: http://oeis.org/search?q=255%2C2915%2C16383%2C62499%2C186623%2C470595%2C1048575%2C2125763%2C3999999%2C7086243%2C11943935%2C19307235&sort=&language=&go=Search

Comment: That's a pretty good fit. With twelve terms, an exact-fit polynomial could be up to degree 11.

Comment: @AnonymousPi Have you tried factoring that? (With Wolfram Alpha, I guess)

Comment: If they are $n(n-2)$ then they are $1$ less than perfect squares.  Try $\sqrt{a_n + 1}$.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A067998

Comment: @columbus8myhw Actually, my answer, and ajotatxe's accepted answer are equivalent, it's just that the starting index is different: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4x%5E6%2B24x%5E5%2B60x%5E4%2B80x%5E3%2B60x%5E2%2B24x%2B3%3D4%28x%2B1%29%5E6-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sumbers are of the form $b_n^2-1$, where $b_n=2n^3$. That is, your sequence is
$$a_n=4n^6-1$$
beginninng at $n=2$.

Comment: Woah, thanks a lot!